# ¿ Se pueden agrupar clases en boostrap para utilizarlas de forma conjunta con un nuevo nombre de clase?

Tags: bootstrap

Quisiera saber si se puede agrupar clases de Boostrap para utilizarlas de forma conjunta con un solo nombre.

Por ejemplo

```
<label class="small mb-1" for="inputEmailAddress">Email</label>
```

Ya que "small mb1" es común a todas mis etiquetas de un formulario quisiera poder definir una clase etiqueta= "small mb-1" como una clase combinada o algo así que llamaría etiqueta para hacer algo como esto:

```
<label class="etiqueta" for="inputEmailAddress">Email</label>
```

Lo único que se me ocurre sería ver la definición css que boostrap tiene para esas clases y crearme una clase con la fusión de ambas pero no me gustaría hacer eso. Quisiera saber si hay algún método de obtener la clase "etiqueta" usando las clases de boostrap.

Gracias

Comment: Para lo que quieres hacer necesitas un preprocesador de hojas de estilo como [sass](https://sass-lang.com/), o cualquiera de los otros que hay disponibles. Me temo que con css *puro* no hay manera de *extender* clases :).

Comment: Otra forma, aunque no la recomiendo por temas de legibilidad del código, es usar Javascript. Por otro lado, tu pregunta ya fue realizada en el sitio y tiene respuestas interesantes. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

como tal boostrap no tiene esa funcion, si lo que quieres es algo especifico es mejor crearlo con css, si lo que quieres es poder modificar tus clases se puede usar js para modificar o dar un mismo valor con el siguiente codigo

div id="demo-id">Demo ID /div>

// Both methods will return a single element

const demoId = document.querySelector('#demo-id');

te dejo el enlace de la pagina por si quieres mas informacion:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-modificar-atributos-clases-y-estilos-en-el-dom-es

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero hacerlo con un comentario y un enlace externo se considera de baja calidad, por lo cual tu respuesta puese terminar reportada. Te invito a leer [answer] y a hacer clic en [edit] para que mejores tu respuesta. Lo ideal es que puedas incluir un [mcve] en tu respuesta. Saludos